# I'm translating English to Hindi, what's it called when the translations are with English characters?

Tags: single-word-requests, translation, hindi

I'm translating English to Hindi, what's it called when the translations are with English characters?

For example, "love" comes up as "Pyāra" and "प्यार". I need the "Pyāra" word in my dictionary.

Comment: Below are 2 equally valid answers, romanization and transliteration. I would select the latter, which basically means spelling the *sounds* of words from one language (Hindi) using the *approximate phonetic equivalent* in the alphabet of a different language (English). It should be noted that romanization is a *subset* of transliteration that applies *only* if the output uses the Latin alphabet. For example English words may be phonetically spelled using the Cyrillic alphabet for Russian readers and that would be transliteration but not romanization.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch, I would respectfully disagree. **Transliteration** is the *process*, Romanization and Cyrillization are two of many possible specific *applications* of that process. **Transcribing** is the process of converting spoken sounds to written form, and again Romanization is one of many possible applications of that process, as is Gregg Shorthand (stenography).

Comment: @O.M.Y. I don't disagree, that is I do agree, with your updated comment. Not really to OP's question, but another option is a *phonetic dictionary*; but then you get fəˈnedik ˈdik-shə-ˌner-ē, -ˌne-rē

Comment: @O.M.Y. I would be careful, 'transliteration' is often not the business of supplying approximate phonetic equivalents. It can be, informally, of course; but generally transliteration is quite technical and scientific https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Indic_transliteration, may employ a host of diacritics, e.g. ḍ, may be very formal and standardised and - while it usually tries to use generally appropriate letters - need not give excessive heed to pronunciation, e.g. च (which has a sound like **ch**at) is often transliterated "c" (which doesn't)

Comment: In fact, most formal transliteration schemes try to reflect the original script and transliteration will be letter-for-letter, rather than sound for sound. Which is not to say that no heed at all is paid to pronunciation, far from it, indeed [schwa deletion in Hindi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwa_deletion_in_Indo-Aryan_languages) is usually observed in transliteration

Comment: @Au101 I am confused. The Wikipedia link you provided supports my understanding of what transliteration is. It states: "*The formal transliteration may be used to accurately and unambiguously present the **phonetic content** of the original script.*" [emphasis added]. How do you get this to mean transliteration is *not* based on pronunciation? As for the CH vs C issue, obviously various *dialects* and even various *linguists* will produce different pronunciation and transliteration charts (compare English pronunciation by folks from New Jersey with that of folks from Louisiana for example).

Comment: That's phonetic Hindi I guess? :/

Comment: @O.M.Y. I was using the Wikipedia link to demonstrate the formality of the process. If you scroll down and have a look at the chart, especially the ISO standard, you'll see that there's very little approximation involved. Instead, it's mechanical. The standard provides a letter which you then use. For example, in formal transliteration of Tamil ṭ is always used for the letter ட், even though it may be pronounced like a t, or like a d, depending on context, but that isn't reflected in transliteration, because it isn't reflected in Tamil script.

Comment: So, in my experience, learning a transliteration scheme can be almost like learning a whole new script. For example, the formal transliteration of the capital of Yemen is Ṣan`ā'. Now, most native speakers of English will, I think, have a hard time working out what that's supposed to mean. Approximating the pronunciation of this name would give us the informal transliteration Sana'a, or Sanaa, or Sana. But, of course, the letters chosen are supposed to be as logical as possible, I just wanted to expand a little on your comment, I wasn't trying to say you're wrong

Comment: As a francophone I do understand about pronunciation in context. It is my belief that much of transliteration is often done on a word-by-word -- and the occasional inseverable phrase -- basis, disregarding context. Much as one would include stand-alone phonetic spellings when creating a dictionary. Thanks Au101.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

**Transliteration** may be the word you're looking for: "Pyāra" is the *transliteration* of "प्यार" into the Latin alphabet.

From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transliteration):

> Transliteration is the conversion of a text from one script to another.
>
> For instance, a Latin transliteration of the Greek phrase "Ελληνική Δημοκρατία", usually translated as 'Hellenic Republic', is "Ellēnikḗ Dēmokratía".

Comment: is there an author you know of that does this?

Comment: @Rob How about [this](http://www.amazon.com/Allied-Transliterated-English-Dictionary-Edition/dp/8186062106)?

Comment: @randal'thor that is a great find for Rob, looks like it is exactly what he wants if I understand his comments correctly.

Answer (score 6):

I believe you are looking for

## Romanization

From the [*romanization*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Romanization) wikipedia,

> Romanization or Latinization (or romanisation, latinisation: see spelling differences), in linguistics, is the conversion of writing from a different writing system to the Roman (Latin) script, or a system for doing so. Methods of romanization include transliteration, for representing written text, and transcription, for representing the spoken word, and combinations of both.

Comment: is there an author you know of that does this?

Comment: For example, Turkish was "romanized" in November 1928 on the initiative of Mustapha Kemal. From [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ottoman_Turkish_alphabet) : "*It was argued that Romanization of the script would detach Turkey from the wider Islamic world*,

Comment: @Rob Can you be more [specific](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Romanization#Romanization_of_specific_writing_systems)?

Comment: yeah I'm looking for a dictionary that includes romanization with its translations

Comment: @Rob [The Oxford Hindi-English Dictionary](http://www.flipkart.com/oxford-hindi-english-dictionary-1st/p/itmdv5pfu4faferu) has a review that says (in part) *the English transliteration is right next to the Devanagari script*.