# Name of languages that don't use English characters?

Tags: transliteration

I'm trying to name a question of mine:

[I'm translating English to Hindi, what's it called when the translations are with English characters?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/287156/im-translating-english-to-hindi-whats-it-called-when-the-translations-are-wit/287158#287158)

And instead of naming it: *I'm translating English to Hindi, what's it called when **the** translations are with English characters?*

I can name it something like: *I'm translating English to Hindi, what's it called when **Non-English Character'd** translations are with English characters?*

Catch my drift?

Comment: It's not called "English" characters. It is called "Latin" character set. That is the internationally accepted name for that character set. ISO-8859-1 or CP-1252.

Comment: Also, your title should be "Names of languages ..." rather than "name of languages". In fact, it should just be "Written languages that don't ..."

Comment: So you'll be creating a "hinglish" dictionary. Get it?

Answer (score 2):

You are looking for an accepted, known term for a non-English charactered language or text. It is common to qualify such a thing as *non-Latin script*. For example:

> Hindi is a non-Latin script language.
>
> The letter was written in a non-Latin script.

You can find more examples by Googling [ [`non-Latin script`](http://www.google.com/search?q=non-Latin+script) ].

So your corrected question might read:

> What’s it called when a translation to a non-Latin script language (or text) uses Latin characters?

(Incidentally, the term for representing a non-Latin script language with Latin characters is “[romanization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Romanization)”, or alternatively “latinization”.)

Answer (score 0):

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_languages_by_writing_system

Given that there are so many types of scripts, I doubt there is a real word for "Non-Latin script" other than that.  So your question might better be phrased "I'm translating English to Hindi; what's it called when Latin script is borrowed into a different script?" or "what's it called when non-Latin scripts use Latin characters?"
By the way the "English characters" are known as "Latin characters."